# How to check if a function's return value is undefined or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, undefined

Hello I'm a beginner at Javascript and I was actually wondering if I made a function like the one below:

```
function doSomething(){
//does something
}
```

After creating this function how do I know if the value returned by this function is undefined or not ? I tried the following to solve my problem:

```
if (doSomething == undefined){//code will do something}
```

and

```
 if (doSomething){//code will do something}
```

and

```
if (typeOf doSomething === undefined){//code will do something}
```

but none of them worked.

So basically the question is how do I check if the return value of this function is undefined or not. Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: You have to **call** the function: `if (doSomething() == undefined)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to **call** the function to get a return value from it.

```
if (typeof doSomething() === 'undefined') {

}
```

If you don't call it,  you don't know what it will return (which might be different depending on what you pass it or some other condition).

```
function doSomething(value) {
    if (value === "Nothing") return undefined;
    return "Something";
}
```